# Android sws_scale RGB0 Frame taking long time and cause video latency

Tags: android, ffmpeg, rgb, yuv, native-activity

Reading frames from FFMPEG and try to directly draw on a surface window in Native android, If scale the image to exact size what we are getting from the camera and apply YUV420P to RGBA it take `1ms` to scale through `av_image_fill_arrays` but if scale image surface size, then It took `25 to 30ms` to scale a same frame.

**Low latency:[~1ms by sws_scale]**

```
swsContext = sws_getContext(videoCodecContext->width,
                                    videoCodecContext->height,
                                    videoCodecContext->pix_fmt,
                                    videoCodecContext->width,
                                    videoCodecContext->height,
                                    AV_PIX_FMT_RGB0,
                                    SWS_FAST_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, NULL);
av_image_fill_arrays()
av_read_frame()
avcodec_decode_video2(
sws_scale(swsContext,
          (const uint8_t *const *) videoFrame->data,
          videoFrame->linesize,
          0,
          videoCodecContext->height,
          pictureFrame->data,
          pictureFrame->linesize);
ANativeWindow_lock()
Write all buffer bytes to window.
ANativeWindow_unlockAndPost()
```

**Low latency:[~30ms by sws_scale]**

```
[videoContext Width: 848 Height: 608]
swsContext = sws_getContext(videoCodecContext->width,
                                    videoCodecContext->height,
                                    videoCodecContext->pix_fmt,
                                    1080,
                                    608,
                                    AV_PIX_FMT_RGB0,
                                    SWS_FAST_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

*NOTE: we are getting YUV420P pixel format.*

Whenever we change context width and height other than videoContext it will take more than 30ms so result is video delaying.

**TRY 1:** Pass the buffer from JNI to Java and create bitmap there to scale later on but createBitmap itself take `~500ms` which is not good enough.

**TRY 2:** Direct YUV420P to RGB conversion, but still `sws_scale` is greater.

**TRY 3:** Direct writes YUV to window bites, but it shows without color (If anyone has a solution here will might helpful).

**TRY 4:** `yuvlib`, still not worth it.

**TRY 5:** Different pixel formats and flags in swsContext.

[image]

Any help would appreciated.

Comment: That actually sounds about rite to me. “sw” in sw_scale stands for software. I would look for an OpenGL/OpenCL solution. It would also prolong batter life.

Comment: @szatmary Thank you for the replay. we are currently using SurfaceView window. not sure how the OpenGL worked in my case. If you can provide some more info will be very helpful.

Comment: Android and MediaCodec are very well documented. You google is the same as mine :)

Comment: Please see *[Hardware scaling the OpenGL surface with NativeActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22169228/192373)*. I believe your question is fully answered there and in the linked [Android Developers blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/09/using-hardware-scaler-for-performance.html).

Comment: Thanks @AlexCohn, let me try OpenGL(beginner).

Comment: WOW! worked Thanks @AlexCohn, working fine with surface view.
`ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry(window, 848, 608, WINDOW_FORMAT_RGBA_8888);`